# Translation of compiling error

Tags: c++

I'm getting these errors and i dont understand why, program compiled fine at school not its bonkers, can anyone translate?.

```
functions.cpp: In function 'void printCreatures(Creatures*, int)':
functions.cpp:248:35: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_fstrea
m<char>::open(std::string&, const openmode&)'
functions.cpp:248:35: note: candidate is:
In file included from Prog4.h:13:0,
                 from functions.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/fstream:871:7: note: void std:
:basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [wit
h _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std
::_Ios_Openmode]
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/fstream:871:7: note:   no know
n conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to
'const char*'
functions.cpp: In function 'void saveCreaturesToFile(Creatures*, int)':
functions.cpp:333:35: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_fstrea
m<char>::open(std::string&, const openmode&)'
functions.cpp:333:35: note: candidate is:
In file included from Prog4.h:13:0,
                 from functions.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/fstream:871:7: note: void std:
:basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [wit
h _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std
::_Ios_Openmode]
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/fstream:871:7: note:   no know
n conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to
'const char*'
```

EDIT: lines 241 -258 I'll edit again and add the rest in a few mins.

```
if (menuOption == '2')
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl << "What is the name of the file you wish to write to? ";
        getline(cin, filename);

        // attempt to open the file.
        dataFile.open(filename, ios::out);

        if (dataFile.fail())    
            cout << endl << endl << "Failed to create " << filename 
                << ", unable to save creatures - file already open?" << endl << endl;
        else
        {
            cout.rdbuf(dataFile.rdbuf());
            redirected = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Were you compiling on Linux at school? Also, were you using the same Makefile?

Comment: It would probably help if you showed us your code.

Comment: You're calling `open()` with a `std::string` when your compiler only supports the `const char*` overload. You need to use `.c_str()` to get a pointer to the buffer.

Comment: Also, the error message in general is not enough to ascertain the problem. We also need the relevant code to go along with it.

Comment: Code is 1400 lines long so no lolz. Yes the computer was using linux now im on windows and need to work here.

Comment: How much of code do Y'all want to see?

Comment: @Baalzamon: You're not supposed to post all your code. You're supposed to post your minimal testcase. Y'know, the one you've been debugging with for the past several hours. http://sscce.org

Comment: Tip: MS seldom has UTF-8 for its narrow charset. Read: [UTF-8 Everywhere Manifesto](http://www.utf8everywhere.org) for pitfalls on Windows and how to get it to work anyway. Also [Boost.Nowide](http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html)

Comment: @Deduplicator: Irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fstream`s can only be opened directly with a `std::string` if you compile with C++11 compatibility, add the `-std=c++11` flag when compiling or open your files by calling the `c_str()` function of your strings.

Comment: Or if you use MSVS (IIRC).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah later versions of VS support the overload, although OP is using MinGW.

Comment: That solved it, is there a way to fix it so i wont have to do that every time i compile?

Comment: Passing the right compiler-flags must be done manually. You might consider a makefile though, maybe even a script.

Comment: @Baalzamon If you have a single source file one super-roundabout way is to set the `CXXFLAGS` environment variable to `-std=c++11`, rename your source file to `whatever.exe.cpp` and run `mingw32-make whatever.exe`. Anything more complicated and you'll need to write a Makefile. You could also rename the binary and create link that calls `g++` with the flag.

Comment: I've got 3 files included in the program.